# Integer operations on cross references

Tags: cross-referencing, calculations, etoolbox

I would like to perform integer operations on a cross reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

hello \label{here}

\ifnumequal{\pageref{here}}{1}{You are on the 1st page}{...}

\end{document}
```

I get *Missing number, treated as zero*, even on a second pass (when the reference is not `??` anymore).

NB: In this MWE, one could obviously use `\thepage`. But this is not an option in the real document.

Comment: Do `\usepackage{refcount}` and use `\getpagerefnumber` instead of `\pageref`.

Comment: egreg, a thousand thanks! I had tried without success many things, not knowing about the `refcount` package... (I wish I could accept your answer).

Comment: It's better to close the question as duplicate, if you agree.

Comment: Please, do so! The questions are close indeed.